# Simple variable(counter) in foreach in jsp

Tags: jsp, variables, foreach, listiterator

I have simple question: Is possible in jsp make variable in foreach where I will store number of iteretion? The question also include how to do it? There is example how I wanna use it. It's this kind of problem that you will solve in few seconds if you know the answer, but its hard to find if you even know how to call it so the simple example explain everything ... 

**Description to the example:** In arraylist list are href values for my tags  which are references for pages. **NUMBER** should represent my variable - something like list iterator. 
So I will get: Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, ... Page x, where x is number of items in list list.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.list}" var="listItem">
<a href="<c:out value="${listItem}" />">Page NUMBER</a>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'varStatus' attribute, that will give you the counter.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.list}" var="listItem" varStatus="counter" >
     <a href="<c:out value="${listItem}" />"><c:out value="${counter}" /></a>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank to pointing me right direction but as I google, cause now I know what to google there should be actually  value="${counter.count}" for counting from 1 what I need or counter.index for counting from 0, but varStatus don't return integer, but some object. There are the another values of that object http://www.bmchild.com/2012/03/jstl-cforeach-varstatus-properties.html